# Is it possible to roll your own 'function' construct or 'eval' method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, eval

Is it at all possible to re-implement 'function' or 'eval' in pure javascript? E.g. lets say I wanted to be able to write the following:

```
// note that I don't want to have to put code in a string here
var x = func() { var something = "nothing"; return something; }
```

or

```
var hiString = 'hi'  // note that it of course needs to be able to access the current context
evaluatize("function hi(){ alert(hiString); } hi();")
```

Are either of these things possible in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a JavaScript interpreter in JavaScript like [Narcissus](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/narcissus/).

Comment: Possibly make the interpreter capable of serving coffee if you choose this approach, it's always useful to have a warm cup of coffee when programming !

Comment: +1 Narcissus, but should note that will only work on firefox & apps using spider-monkey

Answer (score 1):

for the first, I'm not sure if you were asking something different, but this works:

```
var x = function() {return "cake";}
x();
```

Comment: And for the second, just use JavaScript's `eval()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If your needs are simple, then you can do something like this:

```
var generator = function(input) {
    return function() {alert(input)};
};

var helloFunction = generator("Hello, World.");

helloFunction(); // alerts "Hello, World."
```